# How to control Recyclerview item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

[how to control recyclerView item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j92W.png) . i have an layout where i'm using recyclerview for the show list item. i have an EditText & button inside the recyclerview , i want if user'll click on the button then editText should be add into list. it's working but problem is that are adding more than one edittext into list.

```
 holder.addlinetxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {

                jsonObject.put("name", "");
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                GrabAndGoSubLabelsModel addGoGrabLineModal = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonObject), GrabAndGoSubLabelsModel.class);
                grabAndGoSubLabelsModels.add(addGoGrabLineModal);
                addGoGrabLineBackendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                holder.addlineRecyclerview.setAdapter(addGoGrabLineBackendAdapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
    });
```